# Reading and storing a string in java

Tags: java, string

So let's say I'm given a chess piece that is at location "c4", so it's in the 3rd column and 4th row. How would one go about reading this "c4" string and then marking on the board that a piece is there.
I've been thinking one for loop that reads for characters and another that reads for numbers, but not sure how to mark that a piece is in a location like c4.
Any ideas/ideas to push me into right direction?

Comment: Splitting the ``"c4"`` into it's column/row components shouldn't be hard. What do you mean by "marking on the board"?

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: What's your current implementation? what's representing the board and what's representing where you're marking that it's there? Someone would love to help you out I'm sure but there's not really enough to go off of here

Comment: I just can't figure out how to have my program remember that at location c4 there's a chess piece @f1sh

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to store these values with a 2D array like so:

`bool[][] board = new bool[8][8];`

As for reading the string there a many ways you could go about it. I would use `charAt` to pull out the individual characters, then put the first one through a switch statement to find it's numeric value.

```
String input = "c4"
int row = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(1));
char columnChar = input.charAt(0);
int column;
switch (Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(1)) {
    case 'a':
        column = 1;
    case 'b':
        column = 2;
    // etc...
}
board[column - 1][row - 1] = true; // Fill the board, subtracting one to account for arrays indexing from zero
```

Here I used an array of bools to keep track, but of course you'll need something more complicated to keep track of different pieces. Possibility creating a `ChessPiece` class and extending it to create each piece would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you are and are not guaranteed in this situation.  Do you know for a fact the first character will always be a letter?  What is your number limit?

If you're guaranteed the first is always a character, as in a chessboard (an 8x8 grid), then you can just do a simple `myStr.charAt(0)` to get that, do something with that character, then replace what was there and convert the rest a la `myStr.replace(oldChar, '')` and parse it with `Integer.parseInt()`.

If your data is not guaranteed and much more complicated you'll want to break your string into parts, parse through what you break it down to, and do something with the data.  For example if I was given the string `"hh88"`, I would start by finding where my numbers start, separating those two parts out, and doing something with the data from there. The same idea applies if you're not guaranteed the same order i.e. `"8c"` was a valid string entry, the difference here is you'd need to identify where each component was.

Comment: It is guaranteed that a letter is always first

Comment: So myStr,charAt(0) will get the first character. What will the Integer.parseInt() do?

Comment: Then the above should work just fine, more or less identify where the letters stop and numbers end and break your string up that way.  `substring`, `replace`, and `split` (if you're given a delimiter in the entered string) will all work just fine.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` will convert the value stored in the string into an integer if it is a valid value (no letters or special characters).  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-